# Exception Unhandled Error when trying to use function in catch block

Tags: c++

I am trying to run a simple code where an error is throw when the its looking for a vector position out of range. But when I run the code, I get an error

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

void error()
{
    throw(" a standard exception was caught, with message \n");
}

int main() {

    try {
        cout << "Creating a vector of size 5... \n";
        vector<int> v(5);
        cout << "Accessing the 11th element of the vector...\n";
        cout << v.at(10);
    }
    catch (const exception& e) {
        error();
    }
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "I get an error"; what kind of error?

Comment: First of all, do not throw `const char*`, if you must throw something, throw `std::exception` (or any subclass). You "got an error" because you are thrownig exception in the catch block.

Answer (score 2):

The `error()` function executes properly. It throws an unhandled exception inside the `catch` block. Modify the function to catch and handle the exception:

```
void error() {
    try {
        throw(" a standard exception was caught, with message \n");
    }
    catch (char const* e) {
        std::cout << "Exception thrown: " << e;
    }
}
```

That being said, you probably need a simple:

```
catch (const exception& e) {
    std::cout << e.what();
}
```

instead, not a function that throws an unhandled `char const*` exception.

Answer (score 0):

So the `at` function threw an exception, which is what you want. It made control jump to the `catch` block as expected, ready for you to take some alternative/remedial action.

But then, from the `catch`, you just threw another exception! There's nothing handling this one. You'd have needed a second `try`/`catch` pair wrapped around the whole lot in order to catch that one (because that's what happens when you throw an exception from a `catch` for some other exception).

It's not clear what you wanted to do instead, but perhaps writing to `std::cerr` will suffice?